# c# dynamic proxy

Tags: c#, nhibernate, dynamic, proxy

How determine in C# if an Object is the original object or a dynamic proxy of the original object?

I run into this need playing with nhibernate.

Answer (score 3):

Answer is here in a [previous question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664245/identifying-nhibernate-proxy-classes)

> You can detect if a class is a
>   NHibernate proxy by casting it to
>   (unsurprisingly) INHibernateProxy.
>
> If you need to get the underlying
>   "real" object, use:
>
> Session.GetSessionImplementation().PersistenceContext.Unproxy(proxiedObject)
>   You don't need to test for proxies to
>   call Unproxy; it returns the original
>   parameter if it's not a proxy.