# ObjectDataSource fails to bind list when NHibernate Proxy object if on the first position

Tags: asp.net, .net, nhibernate, castle-dynamicproxy

I have a select method for ObjectDataSource:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Model.Domain.Theme> Select()
    {
        var cycleRepo = new RbaCycleRepository(Global.sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession());
        RbaCycle lacOpenCycle = cycleRepo.FindLacOpenCycle();
        if (lacOpenCycle != null)
        {
            var themeRepo = new ThemeRepository(Global.sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession());
            var result = themeRepo.FindAll(new ThemesForCycle(lacOpenCycle).GetQuery());
            return result;
        }
        return Enumerable.Empty<Model.Domain.Theme>();
    }
```

And here is the scenario:

- I click on the button, some actions are performed and as a result I end up with a few proxy *Theme* objects in 1st level cache - which is fine.
- *Select()* method is called and it returns result. The result can contain only *Theme* objects or a mix of *Theme* and *NHibernate Castle Proxy* (for instance). This is a trace from watch window:

> {Castle.Proxies.ThemeProxy}   Model.Domain.Theme
>   {Castle.Proxies.ThemeProxy} {Model.Domain.Theme}  Model.Domain.Theme

- If the first object in the result collection is actual *Theme* object, then binding of the whole collection succeedes. **But if first element in collection is Proxy object**, then I end up with exception:

> Unhandled exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of
>   type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. --->
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Property accessor 'Title'
>   on object 'CIPNet.Model.Domain.Theme' threw the following
>   exception:'Object does not match target type.' --->
>   System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.

EDIT: This is FindAll implementation:

```
    public IList<T> FindAll(QueryOver<T, T> query)
    {
        return query.GetExecutableQueryOver(session).List();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the temp solution I came up with. It works, I just make sure that list which is binded to control has first object that is not proxy:

```
    public static IList<T> ToProxySafeList<T>(this IList<T> list)
        where T: class
    {
        if (list.Count == 0) return list;

        var proxy = list[0] as INHibernateProxy;
        if (proxy != null)
        {
            list[0] = proxy.HibernateLazyInitializer.GetImplementation() as T;
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `ObjectDataSource` is using the first element of the collection to figure out the columns for data source. Since it's using reflection, NHibernate / Castle DynamicProxy doesn't have a chance to unproxy the object. You'll probably need to do that manually.

[Identifying NHibernate proxy classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664245/identifying-nhibernate-proxy-classes)
[NHibernate: Get concrete type of referenced abstract entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229510/nhibernate-get-concrete-type-of-referenced-abstract-entity)

Also, if your `FindAll` method is returning `IQueriable` or `IEnumerable`, try to call `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` on result, to force the query execution. You might not need to unproxy manually:

```
var result = 
    themeRepo.FindAll(new ThemesForCycle(lacOpenCycle).GetQuery()).ToList();
```