# Are there occasions when NHibernate won't return a proxy object?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm learning Fluent NHibernate (and by extension, NHibernate generally). I'm using auto-mapping with some overrides, but I don't think that is important for the question (of course, if I'm wrong here I'll gladly update the question).

Given an `ISession` (and a few more assumed variables) I can return entities by their ID:

```
using (var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    var user = session.Get<User>(userId);
}
```

My limited understanding was that NHibernate creates a proxy around the `User` mapped entity, yet when I test it ([based on this](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664245/identifying-nhibernate-proxy-classes&ei=IqtsT7HXConD0QX2mKnEBg&usg=AFQjCNFcxXFnRmxfJ4wuxvVO1Cqt3y8pPw&sig2=aFy6oYiaPeMOQD6cXwqWAg)):

```
Assert.That(user is INHibernateProxy, "Not a proxy.");
```

It appears as though my instance is not a proxy.

**Are there occasions where proxies are not used?** I'm hoping for the "missing piece" and praying this isn't the Friday afternoon brain-fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally proxies are for lazy loading. Whenever you're fetching entitles by `Get` etc., you're not getting proxies, but the real objects. NHibernate don't use proxies when not necessary.

But if `user` has an `Address`, `user.Address is INHibernateProxy` will be true (unless lazy loading is turned off for this relationship).

For more info about how and when NHibernate handles proxies, see [this article](http://davybrion.com/blog/2009/03/must-everything-be-virtual-with-nhibernate/).

Comment: Ah, so the missing piece here is root objects or non-lazy objects are physical objects. And proxies are only used for supporting lazy load?

Comment: Yes, I think that proxies are for lazy loading only.

Comment: Yeah that article helps. Thanks for the clarification, I won't expect types to be proxies all the time from now on.

Answer (score 4):

As NOtherDev stated, proxies are for lazy-loading. But even `Session.Get` sometime returns a proxy. This caught me off guard several times. If you use lazy loading for any column in the table by specifying `lazy="true"` like this:

```
<property name="Description" type="StringClob" not-null="false" lazy="true"/>
```

Session.Get will always return proxies for this type, and there is no way to unproxy the object. In fact, the proxy is the real object.

By the way, disabling lazy-loading is really, really a bad idea. You can read more about that here: [NHibernate is lazy, just live with it](http://ayende.com/blog/4573/nhibernate-is-lazy-just-live-with-it)

Comment: What if I never ever want to use a proxy object? How can I ensure my objects are unproxied?

Answer (score 4):

Some questions are never too old ;) 
In real live, you usally get proxies by access "parent" of inverse relationship or by loading an object by Load(). But if the object has already been loaded in the cache before, you will get the type of the first access. So Load/Get might both return proxy or real instance.

```
        // if object has been loaded, load will return real instance
        using (var session = CreateSession())
        {
            postByGet = session.Get<Post>(post1Id);
            postByLoad = session.Load<Post>(post1Id);

            Assert.IsFalse(postByGet is INHibernateProxy);
            Assert.IsFalse(postByLoad is INHibernateProxy);
            Assert.IsTrue(object.ReferenceEquals(postByGet, postByLoad));
        }

        // if proxy has been loaded, get will return filled proxy
        using (var session = CreateSession())
        {
            postByLoad = session.Load<Post>(post1Id);
            postByGet = session.Get<Post>(post1Id);

            Assert.IsTrue(postByGet is INHibernateProxy);
            Assert.IsTrue(postByLoad is INHibernateProxy);
            Assert.IsTrue(object.ReferenceEquals(postByGet, postByLoad));
        }
```

Comment: Wow, a mere 8 years ;-)

Answer (score 3):

`ISession.Get` always return either `null` or a real object. `ISession.Load` OTOH *can* return a proxy (or throw an exception), but proxying is a whole other story: your persistent classes should satisfy some preconditions (virtual properties, non-sealed, etc.).

Comment: My understanding, which I think is flawed, was that proxies were always around. If I disable lazy loading, can I avoid proxies entirely?