# NHibernate Futures returns Proxy sometimes, Entity others

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-futures

I have a database fetch that handles a full object graph using multiple future queries.  It looks something like this (class names have been changed to protect the innocent):

```
Foo foo;
var fooFuture = Session.QueryOver<Foo>()
                       .Where(f => f.Id == id)
                       .Future();

// load up the Blah collection for the Foo
Session.QueryOver<Foo>()
       .Fetch(f => f.Blahs).Eager
       .Where(f => f.Id == id)
       .Future();

// do a separate query for the BlahOptions -- this is needed
// because if we did a Join and Join off of Foo, we'd get duplicate Blah
// results and that's not good
Session.QueryOver<Blah>()
       .Fetch(b => b.Options).Eager
       .Where(b => b.Foo.Id == id)
       .Future();

// load up the Attributes for the Foo
Session.QueryOver<Foo>()
       .Fetch(f => f.Attributes).Eager
       .Where(f => f.Id == id)
       .Future();

foo = fooFuture.SingleOrDefault();
```

*NOTE: I can implement this in NHibernate LINQ, but the behavior remains the same.*

**The weirdness:** `foo` will sometimes be of type `FooNamespace.Foo` (the correct, concrete type) and other times it will be `Castle.Proxies.FooProxy`.

Whether I get the real type or a proxied type seems to depend on whether or not NHibernate has been used previously in the session.  When this query occurs after other NHibernate queries, it returns a `FooProxy`.  If it's the first use of the session, it returns a `Foo`.

**Why does this happen?  How can I prevent it from happening?**  I'm purposefully fetching the entire object graph of `Foo` to make sure there are no proxies.  And graph itself doesn't contain any proxies, it's just the root `Foo` reference.  The fact that the returned type depends on what NHibernate has done before seems to be the key (and really weird).

A couple closing notes:

- `NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized` returns true when fed a `FooProxy`, so I can't assure it's not a proxy that way
- I'm proxy-adverse because the graph will be serialized for caching purposes and deserialization croaks when working with `FooProxy`

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should use NH's caching capabilities, NOT serialize persistent entities.

Comment: I'm doing this in addition to NH's caching capabilities.  We want to store queries and full object graphs -- both of which would result in a 2nd level cache hit per entity using NH's default 2nd level behavior.

Comment: The default behavior is not to cache anything. But both things can be cached easily.

Comment: "Both things can be cached easily" -- Caching a query results in a list of IDs of the objects in the query.  Each ID in the collection will result in a round-trip fetch to 2nd level caching.  Caching a full object graph in NH would result in a 2nd level cache entry (and fetch) for each entity in the graph.  Both provide N+1-like behavior when reading from the 2nd level cache.  I'm trying to prevent that.

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect. If you cache BOTH the queries AND the entities referenced by the ids, there will be no roundtrips.

Comment: I disagree and it's not what I've seen in practice.  Caching the query results in an entry in the 2nd level cache of a collection of ODs, i.e.: {1, 2, 3, 4}.  Those entities are NOT resolved at the 2nd level cache, but are instead returned to the server, where each of those IDs are then resolved (either from the session cache (1st level), from 2nd level cache, or from the database).  I've got the NHProf results to prove it.  I'd love to be proven wrong, though.

Comment: What do you mean by "returned to the server [...] then resolved [...] from 2nd level cache"? Returned to what server? Anyway, here's a blog post about this. Just read it: http://ayende.com/blog/4046/nhibernate-beware-of-inadvisably-applied-caching-strategies

Comment: query cache and entity caching both enabled:  http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=30vkdpu&s=6 -- sure looks like a N+1 Select issue to me, just from the cache, not the database.

Comment: You are misunderstanding what N+1 is. In short: from DB bad, from cache good. What you're seeing in that screenshot is exactly what you want to see.

Comment: I know what N+1 is.  And that's the behavior here, regardless of the nature of the data store (DB vs cache).  Yes, it *is* the desired behavior (again DB vs cache), but when a cached query returns 500 results, I don't want to be slamming the 2nd level cache 501 times.  Under load, it adds up quickly and that's a chatty network i/o.  By caching the entire list (or object graph, etc) upfront manually, I can reduce cached hits for a given page request from several hundred plus to just 4 or 5.

Comment: Chatty network IO? That would only be the case if you are using a separate server for your cache (something you did not mention). Otherwise, it's just reading from a different memory address. Also, if you are loading hundreds of results for a single page view, something else might be off with the design.

Comment: Our memcache servers are living on different servers, yes.

Comment: "proxy vs real instances" see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59623373/2534462

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason why this would generally happen is because a Foo is loaded elsewhere in the session prior to this point and you are getting the proxy created on that previous query.

I have had some success with the following

```
var fooProxy = foo as INHibernateProxy;
if(fooProxy != null) {
   var context= Session.GetSessionImplementation().PersistenceContext;
   foo = context.Unproxy(fooProxy);
}
```

Though, In most cases the process of serialization seems to convert the Proxy to the correct type.

Comment: "The reason why this would generally happen is because a Foo is loaded elsewhere in the session prior to this point and you are getting the proxy created on that previous query."  Very useful piece of information, thanks.

Comment: Minor point, but you could replace the null check here with a call to `foo.IsProxy()` if you add `using NHibernate.Proxy`.